# How to resolve the ValueError proj_w in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, web-services, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have created a REST webservice to execute machine translation with some modifications in translate.py. If I run decode function in translate.py alone, on multiple runs I get the right output. But when I try to run the decode function through the webservice that I have created, the first time, I get the translation result. But on the second iteration, I get an error mentioned in the title.

this is the error message I get : ValueError : Variable proj_w already exists, disallowed. did you mean to set reuse=true in VarScope?

REST webservice part :

```
input = request.json['inputtext']
print "'%s'" % input
print 'Please wait'
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
#out = demo1.decode(input);
```

Decode python script:

```
def decode(sentence)

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Create model and load parameters.

model = create_model(sess, True)
model.batch_size = 1  # We decode one sentence at a time.

# Load vocabularies.
en_vocab_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir,
                             "vocab%d.en" % FLAGS.en_vocab_size)
fr_vocab_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir,
                             "vocab%d.fr" % FLAGS.fr_vocab_size)
en_vocab, _ = data_utils.initialize_vocabulary(en_vocab_path)
_, rev_fr_vocab = data_utils.initialize_vocabulary(fr_vocab_path)

# Decode from standard input.
#sys.stdout.write("> ")
#sys.stdout.flush()
#sentence = sys.stdin.readline()
print ("reading line %s" % sentence)

token_ids = data_utils.sentence_to_token_ids(tf.compat.as_bytes(sentence), en_vocab)
bucket_id = min([b for b in xrange(len(_buckets))
                   if _buckets[b][0] > len(token_ids)])
encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, target_weights = model.get_batch(
      {bucket_id: [(token_ids, [])]}, bucket_id)

_, _, output_logits = model.step(sess, encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs,
                                   target_weights, bucket_id, True)
outputs = [int(np.argmax(logit, axis=1)) for logit in output_logits]
if data_utils.EOS_ID in outputs:
    outputs = outputs[:outputs.index(data_utils.EOS_ID)]
#print(" ".join([tf.compat.as_str(rev_fr_vocab[output]) for output in outputs]))
str1 = ([tf.compat.as_str(rev_fr_vocab[output]) for output in outputs])
output = ' '.join(str1)

print ("output line %s\n" % output)
sys.stdout.flush()
sess.close()
return output
```

It works the first time. But for the next hit on the webservice, I get this error "**ValueError : Variable proj_w already exists, disallowed. did you mean to set reuse=true in VarScope?**"

Comment: In general, you want to create your model *once*, and call it via sess.run() many times. From a brief skim of your code, it looks like you're trying to rebuild the model on each call to decode().

Comment: You are right. I was building the model for each call. I have changed it now and it seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

With the following modifications, I am able to run the webservice smoothly. I am creating the model and tf.session() only once. Earlier they were created for every hit on the webservice.

```
model = None
en_vocab_path =None
fr_vocab_path =None 
sess = None

def decode(sentence)
   global sess

   if sess==None:
     sess = tf.Session()

   global model
   global en_vocab_path
   global fr_vocab_path

   if model==None:
    model = create_model(sess, True)
    model.batch_size = 1  # We decode one sentence at a time.

   # Load vocabularies.
   if en_vocab_path==None:
     en_vocab_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir,
                             "vocab%d.en" % FLAGS.en_vocab_size)
   if fr_vocab_path==None:
     fr_vocab_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir,
                             "vocab%d.fr" % FLAGS.fr_vocab_size)
```